# How to find dwrite_2.h when compile gvim

Tags: vim, compilation

When I compile [gvim](https://github.com/vim/vim/archive/v8.1.1244.zip) on win10 using [Mingw64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z), a problem came.

```sh
gui_dwrite.cpp:42:23: fatal error: dwrite_2.h: No such file or directory
 # include <dwrite_2.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make: *** [Make_cyg_ming.mak:970: gobji686/gui_dwrite.o] Error 1
```

But `dwrite_2.h` in `C:\MinGW\x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include`, what can I do?

Thank firstly!!!

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems related to the COLOR_EMOJI option though I haven't verified this. Try adding this option to your build settings:

`COLOR_EMOJI=no`

Here is the referenced information:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/WxqcR2Z_3hI
https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/2440